# Use Nautilus to open an SSH connection using hostname

Tags: networking, nautilus, ssh, file-sharing, hostname

I'm trying to SSH another machine on my LAN using the hostname because the local IP address gets re-assigned somewhat regularly *(we have issues with our ISP and frequently have to reset our network)*.

I have a laptop with the login `freedom@flex15` and currently local IP `192.168.1.11`

and I have a desktop I am trying to connect to for file transfer with the login `freedom@barton` and local IP `192.168.1.153`

I think I just need some formatting clarification on how to connect using hostname. All the guides I read say to use something like:

```
ssh://username@hostname
```

but if I try:

```
ssh://freedom@barton
```

I get this error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong.
Unable to find the requested location. Please check the spelling or the network settings.
```

However, when using:

```
ssh://freedom@192.168.1.153
```

It works fine. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here because all the documentation says I can use ssh://hostname or ssh://username@hostname or something like that. It would be ideal to have some way to specific this machine that does not involve the IP address. Thank you.

Comment: Try `freedom@barton.local`.

Answer (score 4):

"192.168.1.153" is a private ip address on a LAN.

So, on the server (192.168.1.153) set a static ip address if you have not already.

On the client, edit /etc/hosts

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and add a line at the bottom -

> 192.168.1.153  barton

You should then be able to run ssh://freedom@barton

Comment: But `ssh://freedom@192.168.1.153` apparently works fine... Do you mean `ssh://freedom@barton`?

Comment: yes, lol. Fixed